# How do I invoke a coroutine and gets its Job reference to be used at some other point and listen for completion?

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I'm setting up a test scenario. I have two Activities.

- SplashActivity
- HomeActivity

And a repository named `Repository` which is injected into both of these activity's viewmodels. It's a singleton as well. Let's say the `Repository` class looks like this.

```
class Repository {
    suspend fun getData(): List<Data> {
        delay(20000)
        return // the list
    }
}
```

Now here is the problem statement. Let's say I wanna invoke this getData() method from `SplashActivity`'s viewmodel and skip to `HomeActivity`. And in `HomeActivity`'s viewmodel, I wanna listen to the method I called in SplashActivity and wait for it to complete.

So rather than getData() running it's delay method again, I wanna continue the previous call from `SplashActivity` and wait for it to finish and get the data.

How can I go ahead and do that? I have an answer in my mind. But it looks like a bit of hack to me. Would like to know of better solutions. Also lemme know if I'm thinking of coroutines wrongly.

Answer (score -1):

I'd probably go around with using the CoroutineLiveData since you're already using the lifecycle library. That way your data will be always available regardless of the caller scope. Execution will not be interrupted with unregistering the observer.

```kotlin
class Repository {

    val data = liveData {
        emit(getData())
    }

    private suspend fun getData(): List<Data> {
        // work
        return listOf(...)
    }

}
```

---

In case you need to use multi-state callbacks (for eg. having to switch between "home" and "login" in mid-execution), your choice should be kotlinx channels or flows. In that case you might find handy [Vessel](https://github.com/skoumalcz/teanity/blob/1.2/component/src/main/java/com/skoumal/teanity/component/channel/Vessel.kt) from [teanity](https://github.com/skoumalcz/teanity).

```kotlin
class Repository {

    val dataVessel = Vessel<MyData>()

    data class MyData(...): Vessel.Sailor
    
    fun requestData() {
        repositoryScope.launch { // scope defined manually for your repo or inherited one
            delay(3000) // do work
            dataVessel.sail(MyData(...)) // sail vessels at will
            delay(3000) // do more work
            dataVessel.sail(MyData(...)) // sail vessels at will
        }
    }
}

val repository = Repository()

viewModelScope.launch { // scope will get cancelled with clearing viewModel
    repository.dock().collect { ... }
}
```